# Mongodb select collection is not working in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to get the data from the mongo db table (location) for this i am
trying to use selectCollection() function of mongo db but it is giving following error i am new on mongo db that why i am not getting why this error
occured.

```
object(MongoCollection)#3 (2) { ["w"]=> int(1) ["wtimeout"]=> int(10000) }
```

Below is my php code

```
<?php
$host = "xxxx";
$user = "xxxx";
$pass = "xxx";
$db = "xxxx";
$port = "xxxx";

$con = new MongoClient("mongodb://{$host}:{$port}");
$data = $con->selectDB($db);
if ($user != '' && $pass != '')
    $record=$data->authenticate($user, $pass);
$location = $data->selectCollection('location');
var_dump($location);die;   
?>
```

Please help me thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's no error, that is a collection oject

Comment: $lat ='22.7196';
                $long ='75.8577';
                $cond = array(
                'geoNear' => 'vehicleTypes',
                'near' => array((double) $long, (double) $lat));
                $resultArr1 = $this->mongo->selectCollection('$cmd')->findOne($cond);
                var_dump($resultArr1['results']);die;

Comment: i have also tried above comment code but this is also come null value but i have a record of same lat long in my db  i am not getting what is the problem

Comment: so your collection name is `$cmd`?

Comment: actually some body else is written this code and in which they write above 
code which i have posted but when i tried to run this code its is giving me 
null value i am not geting why because the record is already exist in database.ne thing also i am not getting that how can i check if connection is successfully made withi mongo db or not using php script.

Comment: If connection was not made you would get an exception, like a find exception. To me, the code looks wrong

Comment: Also this using an very old mongodb driver which is no longer properly supported, especially with the authenticate method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132703/discussion-between-varun-joshi-and-sammaye).